# 2D array being reset to it's original values

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, methods

I am working on a sudoku game and I am using the method of creating a solved puzzle and then "digging holes" to get the puzzle that is displayed to the user. For some reason, the testingPuzzle array is being reset to the numbers array every time it goes through the loop. It is true that the testingPuzzle array should be set to the numbers array originally, but it should be edited one spot at a time every time it goes through the loop and have a bunch of zeroes in it after a few iterations. Here is the loop itself:

```
    do{
        x = Math.abs(rand.nextInt() % 9);
        y = Math.abs(rand.nextInt() % 9);
        takeaway_num = testingPuzzle[x][y];
        testingPuzzle[x][y] = 0;
    } while (arraysEqual(solvePuzzle(testingPuzzle), numbers));
```

SolvePuzzle is a method that solves the given puzzle as parameters and returns that solved puzzle. So basically `arraysEqual(solvePuzzle(testingPuzzle), numbers)`checks to see if testingPuzzle is solvable
I am setting the testingPuzzle array equal to the numbers array before the do while loop. It looks like this:

```
int[][] testingPuzzle = new int[9][9];
    for(int y = 0; y < 9; y++){
        for(int x = 0; x < 9; x++){
            testingPuzzle[x][y] = numbers[x][y];
        }
    }
```

Just so you know numbers is the sodoku answer that was generated in a previous method.

I am using my own method for testing if the arrays are equal, called "arraysEqual because I thought .equals() was the problem originally. Here is the method I am using for this:

```
private static boolean arraysEqual(int[][] a, int[][] b){
    for(int y = 0; y < 9; y++){
        for(int x = 0; x < 9; x++){
            if(a[x][y] != b[x][y]){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I'm not really sure why the testingPuzzle Array is being set to the same as the numbers array at the end of each loop. I think it could have something to do with passing the actual array vs. a copy of it to a method that takes in an array but I'm not sure how that works in java.

Comment: I'd suggest you fire up a debugger and step through the code manually. Besides that the problem most likely is you working of references instead of copies. Note that Java is call-by-reference for objects, i.e. if you pass an array (which is an object) into a method any changes the method does to the array will be visible outside that method.

Comment: Could you try and post the relevant code as a whole (leave out methods that don't seem to be relevant but add those that are entirely - as concise as possible though)? What we'd need to know, for example, would be where you initialize `testingPuzzle` and what `solvePuzzle()` looks like.

Comment: Hint: of course, the first "natural" choice when implementing sudoko stuff is a two dimensional array ... but: the **really** natural thing when doing OO design is to abstract such things. So, just as a side note: consider stepping back and designing some more abstract representation of the sodoku board.

Comment: You were right Thomas solvePuzzle() was changing the array itself not a copy of it when I passed the array to the solvePuzzle() method. I fixed it my creating a copy of the array inside the beginning of the method and using that instead of the passed array.